# Bitmap image not accepting pixel array values

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am working on a simple image manipulation image library and i am creating 1 bit per pixel images with it. I am taking the help of the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). I am using the BITMAPINFOHEADER and i am making the file as guided by the wiki. Although it does not work just like that and when i try to open it, the viewer says the file is corrupted. I have taken care of padding and how each row should start with an offset of a multiple of 4 bytes.

I have tried adding each byte manually and making the image in a hex editor myself and it won't work. But when i add 8 more bytes of any kind of information at the end of the file, it gets accepted and viewed just like it should by the viewer. Can anyone tell me why it is so ?

[image]

The above is a 600 x 600 image that works after i added 8 bytes of information to the end.

I would recommend using a hex editor like [HexEd](https://hexed.it/) to view my problem.

All the code is in this [github repository](https://github.com/EliteGamerSiddhu/BiImage)

To function to create the above image (does not work, works after 8 bytes are added at the end of the file) is

```py
from Library.bpp import Img

samp = Img.new(600, 600, 1, 'INFO', colour= '0')
samp.save('lol.bmp')
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a minimal, complete runnable version of your latest/greatest code. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added the function code that makes the pixel array

Comment: That's neither complete nor runnable. It does't show how you create the BMP header either. Nor do you explain how/where adding 8 bytes makes a difference. Try using the debugger to check things. Try making it simpler, by making a really simple all white or all yellow image, then make alternating black and white lines or similar to you build experience and confidence.

Comment: Also try to see if any tools will give you a hint as to what is wrong, e.g. `exiftool -v YOURIMAGE` or `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did not give the bitmap header part since i am sure there is no problem there as changing from info header to core header still works with the working pixel array. The code is seperated in many files and i have made many classes so it is problematic to give it all in one question. I am going to upload it all to github and then attach the link in the question